# Обработка response от SOAP, rest assured

Tags: java, soap, rest

Всем привет . 
Посылаю на SOAP service запрос вида с помощью rest assured:

```
String xml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                +
                "   <soap:Body>\n"
                +
                "      <ns3:HashRequest xmlns:ns2=\"url/ws/types/\" xmlns:ns3=\"url/ws/common/data/\">\n"
                "         <fileKeys>\n"
                +
                "            <objectId>ID</objectId>\n"
                +
                "      
                "         </fileKeys>\n"
                +
                "      </ns3:HashRequest>\n"
                +
                "   </soap:Body>\n"
                +
                "</soap:Envelope>";
        final String response =
                given()
                        .contentType(ContentType.TEXT)
                        .body(xml)
                        .when()
                        .post(WSDL_URL).andReturn().getBody().prettyPrint();
```

В ответ получаю soap ответ в body которого есть hash :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body><ns3:HashResponse xmlns:ns3="URL/ws/common/data/" xmlns:ns2="URL/ws/types/">
<fileHashes>
<hash>Zw1rkmLZXgRUAD2t9XbD+d7o70OjKXbmiPluJb54Qfs=</hash>
</ns3:HashResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

У меня возникла проблема, как мне можно выдернуть из ответа данные в блоке hash ??? 
Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас точно ответ в виде **невалидной** XML?

Если у Вас все же ошибка в вопросе и XML **валидная** (то есть с закрывающимися тегами), то получить можно так:

```
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    import java.io.StringReader;

    public class XPathHelp {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException {
            String xml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
                "    <soap:Body>\n" +
                "        <ns3:HashResponse xmlns:ns3=\"URL/ws/common/data/\" xmlns:ns2=\"URL/ws/types/\">\n" +
                "            <fileHashes>\n" +
                "                <hash>Zw1rkmLZXgRUAD2t9XbD+d7o70OjKXbmiPluJb54Qfs=</hash>\n" +
                "            </fileHashes>\n" +
                "        </ns3:HashResponse>\n" +
                "    </soap:Body>\n" +
                "</soap:Envelope>";
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String hash = (String) xPath.evaluate(
                "//*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='HashResponse']/fileHashes/hash",
                new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)),
                XPathConstants.STRING
            );
            System.out.println(hash);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Всем спасибо разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Вот полный вывод ответа от SOAP:

```
--uuid:uid
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body><ns3:HashResponse xmlns:ns3="URL/ws/common/data/" xmlns:ns2="URL/ws/types/">
<fileHashes>
<hash>Zw1rkmLZXgRUAD2t9XbD+d7o70OjKXbmiPluJb54Qfs=</hash>
</fileHashes>
</ns3:HashResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

--uuid:uid--
```

Я попробовал применить ваш совет к сожалению он выдает ошибку:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context